# CMake static library not found

Tags: c++, cmake, g++

im trying to link a static library (libglfw3.a). The library is place in my "lib" folder which is in the root directory of my project. I keep getting the error which can be found at the bottom. Hope someone can help me. Thanks in advance!

Here is my CMakeLists.txt:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.12)
project(GLFWGLADSTUFF)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 11)

set(SOURCES
    src/main.cpp
    src/glad.c
)

INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES(include)

add_executable(GLFWGLADSTUFF ${SOURCES})

target_include_directories(GLFWGLADSTUFF
    PUBLIC src
    PUBLIC include
)

target_link_libraries(GLFWGLADSTUFF
    lib/libglfw3.a
)
```

Error:

```
Consolidate compiler generated dependencies of target GLFWGLADSTUFF
[ 33%] Linking CXX executable GLFWGLADSTUFF
ld: library not found for -llib/libglfw3.a
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
make[2]: *** [GLFWGLADSTUFF] Error 1
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/GLFWGLADSTUFF.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

Comment: I think you need an absolute path: https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/target_link_libraries.html

Answer (score 0):

```
link_directories(lib)
target_link_libraries(GLFWGLADSTUFF glfw3)
```

should resolve your issue. CMake is not recognizing your path as a path, but as the library name.

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> target_link_libraries(GLFWGLADSTUFF
>    lib/libglfw3.a
> )
> ```

Will not work. You can:

- specify the linker path and the name to be linked (i.e. other answer)
- or preferably, use an `IMPORTED` `add_library`. There is even nice [cmake documentation](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/git-stage/guide/importing-exporting/index.html#importing-libraries) on the topic.